# Configuración de registros MX y direcciones de SPF para evitar ser SPAM para Gmail

Tags: email, dns, g-suite

Los correos que envío con `@piedica.com` están llegando a SPAM de Google. Ya seguí las indicaciones de *Check MX* pero sigo llegando a SPAM, ¿qué puedo hacer o con quién puedo pedir ayuda?

[image: Captura de pantalla del toolbox de googleapps]

Comment: En lo que respecta a esta pregunta, si bien de la imagen podemos inferir varias cosas, la pregunta debería incluir de forma textual toda la información relevante en particular pero sobre todo debe estar dentro de la temática del sitio. No estoy del todo seguro que la configuración del correo electrónico de G Suite esté dentro de la temática actualmente. En cualquierc caso, la imagen muestra con el indicador en rojo las cosas que se tienen que corregir en primer lugar.

Comment: Hola Carlos. Estoy haciendo comprobaciones y tu registro TXT de SPF ya no es el mismo que se muestra en la captura de pantalla. Imagino que con el cambio que has hecho se han solucionado los problemas relativos a SPF, ¿cierto?. Aparecen otros problemas como que no deberían aparecer otros servidores MX que no sean los de google, pero eso veo que aún no lo has arreglado (o quizá no quieras hacerlo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cada vez que configuras un correo con G Suite es bueno agregar SPF y DKIM dentro del DNS de tu dominio. Esto ayuda a que los servidores reconozcan que tu dominio es confiable y que tus correos no se marquen como spam, el DKIM ayuda a la prevension de spoofing en los correos salientes, con DKIM se incluye una firma cifrada en el encabezado de todos los mensajes salientes. Los servidores de correo electrónico que reciben estos mensajes utilizan DKIM para descifrar el encabezado del mensaje y verificar que no se ha modificado tras el envío, para esta configuracion visita https://support.google.com/a/answer/174124?hl=es.

Con respecto al SPF "Como el spoofing es un modo habitual de enviar correo no autorizado, algunos servidores de correo electrónico exigen el SPF. En consecuencia, si no lo configuras en tu dominio, es posible que tus mensajes reboten o se marquen como spam." para mas informacion visita https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=es.

Te sugiero que contactes al equipo de soporte de G Suite para que te puedan ayudar y dar una mejor explicacion y que te puedan ayudar a configurar correctamente tu DNS https://gsuite.google.com/support/.